# Breaking functions down in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

In my attempt to become a better developer I'm trying to refactor the below Node code into 2 (or even 3) separate functions.

The code simply takes in a file, parses some of the data, and rewrites the parsed data to another file.

So my question is, can the code below be broken down to 2 functions (one function to read and parse, the other to write)? Can it be broken down even further to 3 functions (one to read and parse, one to write, one that calls the other two)?

I have attempted to refactor the code into 2 functions but am not having any luck

```
const neatCsv = require('neat-csv');;
const fs = require('fs');
const ObjectsToCsv = require('objects-to-csv'); 

fs.readFile('./someFile.csv', async (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    const neat = await neatCsv(data);
    const sortArray = neat.filter((obj) => obj.Type !== 'Name');
    const priceSortArray = sortArray.filter((obj) => +obj.Price > 5);
    const filterSortArray = priceSortArray.sort((a,b) => parseFloat(b.IV) - parseFloat(a.IV));

    (async () => {

        const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(filterSortArray);

        // Save to file:
        await csv.toDisk('./someOtherFile.csv');

    })();
});
```

Comment: In the real world, you would create function to read, to write and 1 function that do the logic.

Comment: If this is working code that you're looking for improvements with, then http://codereview.stackexchange.com is probably where you should post.  Please read the posting rules there first so you format your question appropriately.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try below approach. I hope this is asked by you.

```
const neatCsv = require('neat-csv');;
const fs = require('fs');
const ObjectsToCsv = require('objects-to-csv'); 

const readFile = (filePath) => {
  fs.readFile('./someFile.csv', async (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    };
    const neat = await neatCsv(data);
    const sortArray = neat.filter((obj) => obj.Type !== 'Name');
    const priceSortArray = sortArray.filter((obj) => +obj.Price > 5);
    const filterSortArray = priceSortArray.sort((a,b) => parseFloat(b.IV) - parseFloat(a.IV));
    saveFile(filterSortArray);
  });
}

const saveFile = (filterSortArray) => {
  const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(filterSortArray);
  // Save to file:
  await csv.toDisk('./someOtherFile.csv');
}
readFile();
```

Comment: the readFile functions is not async, its just a function that uses a callback inside but it wont wait to anything it will run it and keep going on

Comment: then please remove async. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Can you please support by marked as answer or upvote? Only if it helps you, thanks